# Is it possible to query JSON data in DynamoDB?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Let's say my JSON looks like this (example provided [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Java.02.html)) -

```
{
    "year" : 2013,
    "title" : "Turn It Down, Or Else!",
    "info" : {
        "directors" : [
            "Alice Smith",
            "Bob Jones"
        ],
        "release_date" : "2013-01-18T00:00:00Z",
        "rating" : 6.2,
        "genres" : [
            "Comedy",
            "Drama"
        ],
        "image_url" : "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/N/O9ERWAU7FS797AJ7LU8HN09AMUP908RLlo5JF90EWR7LJKQ7@@._V1_SX400_.jpg",
        "plot" : "A rock band plays their music at high volumes, annoying the neighbors.",
        "rank" : 11,
        "running_time_secs" : 5215,
        "actors" : [
            "David Matthewman",
            "Ann Thomas",
            "Jonathan G. Neff"
       ]
    }
}
```

I would like to query all movies where `genres` contains `Drama`.

I went through all of the examples but it seems that I can query only on hash key and sort key. I can't have JSON document as key itself as that is not supported.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668561/dynamodb-query-on-sub-field-of-json-object

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot. DynamoDB requires that all attributes you are filtering for have an index.

As you want to query independently of your main index, you are limited to [Global Secondary Indexes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html).

The documentation lists on what kind of attributes indexes are supported:

> The index key attributes can consist of any top-level String, Number, or Binary attributes from the base table; other scalar types, document types, and set types are not allowed.

Your type would be an `array` of Strings. So this query operation isn't supported by DynamoDB at this time.

You might want to consider other NoSQL document based databases which are more flexible like [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas), if you need this kind of querying functionality.

Answer (score 4):

```
    String filterExpression = "coloumnname.info.genres= :param";
    Map valueMap = new HashMap();
    valueMap.put(":param", "Drama");
    ItemCollection scanResult = table
        .scan(new ScanSpec().
            withFilterExpression(filterExpression).
            withValueMap(valueMap));
```

Comment: readers beware - this is scan operation. Scan works very differently than query. Be aware of the costs when choosing scan

Answer (score 3):

One example that I took from AWS Developer Forums is as follows.

We got some hints for you from our team. Filter/condition expressions for maps have to have key names at each level of the map specified separately in the expression attributeNames map.

Your expression should look like this:

```
{
    "TableName": "genericPodcast",
    "FilterExpression": "#keyone.#keytwo.#keythree = :keyone",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
      "#keyone": "attributes",
      "#keytwo": "playbackInfo",
      "#keythree": "episodeGuid"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
      ":keyone": {
        "S": "podlove-2018-05-02t19:06:11+00:00-964957ce3b62a02"
      }
    }
}
```