# DynamoDB query for attlibute set

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am rather new to DynamoDB and currently I'm trying AWS examples with Node.js. I have a question about this tutorial: [AWS tutorial to load a movie DB and query data.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.html)

I would like to search movies that specified actors appeared in.
For example, "Daniel Bruhl" AND "Olivia Wilde".
Another example, "Daniel Bruhl" OR "Hugh Jackman".
Also if possible, I would like to search fuzzy(Ex. "??? Bruhl").

Is it needed to split table or define filter?

Sample Data:

> ```
> {
>     "year" : 2013,
>     "title" : "Turn It Down, Or Else!",
>     "info" : {
>         "directors" : [
>             "Alice Smith",
>             "Bob Jones"
>         ],
>         "release_date" : "2013-01-18T00:00:00Z",
>         "rating" : 6.2,
>         "genres" : [
>             "Comedy",
>             "Drama"
>         ],
>         "image_url" : "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/N/O9ERWAU7FS797AJ7LU8HN09AMUP908RLlo5JF90EWR7LJKQ7@@._V1_SX400_.jpg",
>         "plot" : "A rock band plays their music at high volumes, annoying the neighbors.",
>         "rank" : 11,
>         "running_time_secs" : 5215,
>         "actors" : [
>             "David Matthewman",
>             "Ann Thomas",
>             "Jonathan G. Neff"
>        ]
>     }
> }
> ```

Schema:

> ```
>     TableName : "Movies",
>     KeySchema: [       
>         { AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
>         { AttributeName: "title", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
>     ],
>     AttributeDefinitions: [       
>         { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
>         { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" }
>     ],
>     ProvisionedThroughput: {       
>         ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
>         WriteCapacityUnits: 10
>     }
> ```

Table filled:

> ```
> allMovies.forEach(function(movie) {
>     var params = {
>         TableName: "Movies",
>         Item: {
>             "year":  movie.year,
>             "title": movie.title,
>             "info":  movie.info
>         }
>     };
>
>    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
>        if (err) {
>            console.error("Unable to add movie", movie.title, ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
>        } else {
>            console.log("PutItem succeeded:", movie.title);
>        }
>     });
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Specifying Item Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html) documentation. Your `info` field is JSON, so Dynamo can be told to look at sub-fields, sub-sub-fields, etc.

Then, it's a matter of combining these with [Condition Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html) to get the functionality you desire.

Keep in mind that although these things are *possible*, whether they're efficient still depends on the table schema. [Looking around a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668561/dynamodb-query-on-sub-field-of-json-object) I don't think you could index on the `actors` subfield, so you would need to pull out that data into its own column in order to build an index on it, if you wanted such queries to be fast.